# Is it possible to RDP into Windows Server 2008 on a machine without any video card or integrated graphics?

Tags: video, remote

Basically, I plan to install Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 on a machine by plugging in the video card initially and then I plan to remove it completely because I need the slot for something else.  The motherboard has no integrated graphics.  Would I be able to RDP once I remove the video card even though the motherboard has no integrated graphics?

Comment: related (but not duplicate) question: ["How to boot computer without any video card"](http://superuser.com/questions/628506/how-to-boot-computer-without-any-video-card)

Comment: related (but not duplicate) question: ["Boot Windows Server 2003 without graphic card?"](http://superuser.com/questions/279567/boot-windows-server-2003-without-graphic-card)

Comment: related (but not duplicate) question: ["Install Windows without a graphic card"](http://superuser.com/questions/336354/install-windows-without-a-graphic-card)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the system is turned on and connected to the network, configured properly, etc. then yes, you can. This is how server administrators access "headless" servers

One note though: many BIOSes refuse to boot without graphics. Check your BIOS first, or else you may be head-banging the keyboard. If you have a PC SPEAKER connected to the motherboard (not a speaker system), then it should sound 1 beep if all is well

Comment: But don't most headless servers still have integrated graphics of some sort?

Comment: I've worked on many that either have Integrated, or they need a PCIe video card. But yes, many do still have IGX

Comment: But if my motherboard doesn't have integrated graphics, and let's just assume it doesn't crap out during startup, would it theoretically be possible to remote in?

Comment: Absolutely. That's what I do with my server at home... Used an AGP graphics card to set it up, then took it out and told the BIOS to continue on any errors instead of stopping. I wait about 1 minute before I can remote to it, then I have Windows 7 at my fingertips (I'm a Mac user)

Comment: How is the GUI responsiveness without any graphics chipset?  Smooth?  Slow?

Comment: I do basic stuff with my server (file sharing, stream serving, print serving, PHP/Apache/MySQL and VPN serving). I do VERY basic browsing with it, otherwise it's mostly left alone. It does good *for what I need*