# How to boot computer without any video card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I have a pc with centOs installed. I want to treat it as a server. Then I remove the video card from that pc , but I can never boot it again

> Motherboard: Gigabyte z77 d3sh
>
> CPU: Xeon e3 1230 v2

When I plug the video card out, the computer never boots (because there is no video card, I can't see any messages).

How can I boot the computer without the video card ?

I have tried to find something in bios, but I cannot find what to set.

Comment: What do you mean without video card? Are you going to control it remotely? It shouldn't matter if there is one, the computer must boot without it just fine

Comment: @Alex I have a pc with centOs installed. I want to treat it as a server. Then I remove the video card from that pc , but I can never boot it again.

Comment: So.. with a video card everything worked? Could you ssh to it?

Comment: @Alex Yes. I can ssh to it.

Comment: Try to boot with a graphics card and have a look at this file: `/boot/grub/menu.lst` and find the line about splashimage (comment it out). There can be an issue of hanging at this stage. Could you provide contents of this file? You can share them using: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @Alex I found no menu.list, superised... , And Now I found /etc/grub.conf, seems the same things as menu.list

Comment: @Alex Omg, You are right.... Please make an answer!!!!

Comment: Glad that helped :) Yeah that's basically an alias to `/boot/grub/grub.conf`

Comment: Related (but not duplicate) question: "[Is it possible to RDP into Windows Server 2008 on a machine without any video card or integrated graphics?](http://superuser.com/questions/472391/is-it-possible-to-rdp-into-windows-server-2008-on-a-machine-without-any-video-ca)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to boot with a graphics card and have a look at this file: `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and find the line about splashimage (comment it out). There can be an issue of hanging at this stage if you have no graphics adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need a video card to boot.  Try to ssh into it and see if there are any errors through there.  If you can't find any errors there, reset all BIOS settings.