# Running a computer without Integrated Graphics or Dedicated GPU

Tags: gpu

Is it possible to run a computer without integrated graphics and no dedicated gpu?

If so would it be able to perform basic functions such as browsing the web.

If not then why wouldn't it work?

Comment: If you want pictures on the screen, you need some sort of GPU. CPU's need a VDC to display things, which is a type of GPU.

Comment: The title conflicts with the first line of the question: do you want integrated graphics or not? If not, how can you display the results of web browsing?

Comment: Also perhaps check out [Is it possible to RDP into Windows Server 2008 on a machine without any video card or integrated graphics?](http://superuser.com/questions/472391/is-it-possible-to-rdp-into-windows-server-2008-on-a-machine-without-any-video-ca), [How to boot computer without any video card](http://superuser.com/questions/628506/how-to-boot-computer-without-any-video-card), etc.

Comment: For clarification, you are aiming to run the PC WITHOUT integrated graphics *and* WITHOUT dedicated graphic; as-in without *any* graphics adapter, correct? I ask because you say "*with* integrated graphics" in your question, and while I'm pretty sure that was a typo, it seems to be confusing people.

Comment: yes without any gpu

Comment: How would you "browse the web" without video output?

Comment: got the answer I was looking for. I was curious to whether it would actually allow the computer to boot and would it theoretically still be able to run the browser even though it wouldn't be displayed. Don't think I made it too clear so my apologies

Comment: You'd need a text-only browser (e.g., `lynx`). Y'know, there are actually computers outside the Windows/Mac model. You may have heard of things called "terminals"?

Comment: In Linux, you can set X11 to use the CPU as a software rasterizer.
`In /etc/X11/xorg.conf just set DRIVER to "fbdev".` This replaces the GPU driver with a CPU framebuffer.  Uses more power, and don't expect high frame rates. Most kernels will use `fbdev` by default if no internal or external GPU chipset detected. Useful for unsupported or damaged chipsets.

Comment: You would still need at least a VDC to even get a framebuffer device file in Linux.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Without a video output of any sort your computer will run perfectly fine
   - assuming it is able to boot past the POST test.

The problem will be - how do you get visual feedback of what the    computer is doing?

Without a video out - does the computer have a    keyboard?  Mouse?  network?  Presumably it does have all these things.

This configuration is basically identical to a standard rack mounted    server.

How then does one interact with such computers?

Initially you will need to have a video connection, unless you remove    the hard disk drive and install the Operating System on a video    enabled computer and then return it to this "headless" computer.

Let's presume the computer has an OS installed and is running ... we    just don't see anything.  How to interact with it?

You have the following options (all of which will require some initial "on screen" configuration.

- SSH.  from a remote computer ssh with the -Y option to your headless computer.  If your headless computer and your remote    computer are both a Unix variety with X11, then the graphical user    interface will be output on your remote computer.
- VNC.  Start a VNC server on the headless computer, and connect to it from a remote.  This will provide a facsimile of your headless    computer's desktop in a window on the remote.
- Remote Desktop.  Again, on the headless computer enable RDP, configure, and connect from a remote.  Functionally very similar to    VNC.

Depending on the nature of your computers, any one or combination of    the above will work.

I haven't mentioned a common rack installation option of installing    KVM's because ... those require video output.

Comment: really detailed answer thanks. I'm not actually setting this up I was just genuinely curious after reading about the hardware side of computers

Comment: Machines designed to be used headless are typically equipped with a serial port. Their BIOS (or equivalent) is capable of communicating using said serial port. So it is possible to install the OS using just the serial port for communication.

Comment: Yes, lots of things are possible.  "designed to be headless" ... presumes much beyond what we have in this question.

Answer (score 3):

Without any type of video present, the POST will fail when no video is detected.

[Power on Self Test Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test)

Comment: This is true for e.g. a desktop computer or a laptop, but not all computers need graphics. Some embedded computers, for example.

Comment: Basically in moderns computers fail for POST, but should work if BIOS/EFI allow tecnically.

Comment: "Modern" PC's don't use BIOS', they use EFI, sooooo. ;)

Comment: QQ Right :D....

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.