# What happens if I try to turn on a PC without GPU and with a CPU without graphics?

Tags: motherboard, gpu

I bought a PC with Ryzen 5 3600 (that doesn’t have integrated graphics) and I tried to turn it on without the GPU, but it gave me no life signal, not even the CPU cooler started, like if it was getting no energy at all.
My question is: is this the expected behavior of the motherboard when turning on a PC in this condition? I’m using a Gigabyte AB350M.

Comment: It should fail POST so yes that is expected: https://superuser.com/a/914809/403203

Comment: On second check, it seems that motherboard may be able to but I couldn't find anything conclusive. It depends on the mobo/BIOS if it will POST without video output. Which Gigabyte AB350M is it? I found multiple versions: D3H, DS3H/v2, Gaming 3.

Comment: The version is DS3H V2.

Comment: If it has no form of GPU, it cannot render anything, so Windows will be unable to boot.

Comment: If your firmware supports booting without any form of graphics then it should boot, if it explicitly requires graphics then it won't. Some motherboards support a so-called "headless" mode but generally you need some form of graphics for at least a while in order to go into the firmware configuration screens in order to enable it. Not all systems do support it though. Seems to be a lot of talk but no actual advice for your mobo: https://www.google.com/search?q=AB350M+headless